# Can't open terminal from one of the user accounts

Tags: command-line

I have a administrator account in which if i open the terminal, it like shows up for a fraction of a second and then vanishes. i tried with guest and other user accounts (created from this one). I was able to open terminal. What is the problem? How to open terminal properly from my main account?
I am not even able to do anything on the screen that comes on Ctrl+Alt+F1. Over there, i put my login id and then password then suddenly some text comes there and the next second, vanishes. Asking me to login again

Comment: sorry , updated my answer.

Comment: I'd suggest logging in to a TTY (ctrl+alt+F1) then running `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal`. See if there are any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login there with your name and password and then type below command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal
```

then try again with relogin/restart.

Comment: @rajadenupula Please read the question carefully, i cant access the terminal, so how can i write a command in it? Do u mean from other account (but that wont be of any use will it?)

Comment: @rajegenupula as soon as i type usename and password it again says type username and password

Comment: you giving right info ?

Comment: Yes i am @rajadenupula

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Check the file permissions of new user ( you are logged in as new-set user ! ) for the files of terminal. I assume you have bash as terminal set ? So do find out, where bash is located:

> whereis bash

When there is output like /usr/bin/bash - then do:

> ls -al /usr/bin/bash

Only in case the output at beginning of line is DIFFERENT than this here: -rwxr-xr-x

... then you should do:

> sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/bash

The directories /usr and /usr/bin should be in permission-state of chmod 755 too.

Hope this helps.